# TensorFlow CSV import: adding features and labels to Summary for TensorBoard reads double the lines

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very basic TensorFlow app to test loading the data from CSV line-by-line and adding various summaries and visualizations to TensorBoard. My input CSV file has 18 rows and a bunch of columns -- first XX columns are 'features' and subsequent YY columns are 0s and 1s representing the label.

I noticed that when I create Summaries for the variables that hold Features and Labels, TensorFlow reads twice as many lines from the CSV, so instead of looping 18 times given my 18 rows, I only loop 9. As soon as I remove the code that adds Features and Labels to Summary, the reading goes back to normal. Adding other variables to Summary, such as Cost/etc. that are the output of functions, rather than the CSV, does not have this issue.

I don't yet know whether I will actually need that information in TensorBoard, so I can live without it, but I'd prefer to put in as much info as possible into TensorBoard first, and then decide what I need to keep.

Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

```
    fileName = 'inputFile.csv'
    logs_path = 'log_path'
    try_epochs = 1
    sampling_size = 3
    TS = 479
    TL = 6

    rDefaults = [[0.02] for row in range((TS+TL))]

    def read_from_csv(filename_queue):
        reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=False)
        _, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
        data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=rDefaults)
        features = tf.slice(data, [0], [TS])
        label = tf.slice(data, [TS], [TL])  
        return features, label

    def input_pipeline(batch_size, num_epochs=None):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([fileName], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=False)  
        example, label = read_from_csv(filename_queue)
        example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
            [example, label], 
            batch_size=batch_size)
        return example_batch, label_batch

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, TS], name='pl_one')
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([TS, TL], stddev=1), name='weights')
    b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([TL], stddev=1), name='biaes')
    y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, TL], name='pl_two')

    examples, labels = input_pipeline(sampling_size, try_epochs)

    # this one causes the issue
    with tf.name_scope('Features'):
        features = examples
    # this one also causes the issue
    with tf.name_scope('Labels'):
        labDisp = labels    
    with tf.name_scope('Model'):
        myModel = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y)
    with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
        lossFn = tf.reduce_mean(myModel)
    with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.05).minimize(lossFn)

    a1 = tf.summary.histogram("Features", features)
    a2 = tf.summary.histogram("Labels", labDisp)
    a3 = tf.summary.histogram("Model", myModel)
    a4 = tf.summary.scalar("Loss", lossFn)

    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([a1, a2, a3, a4])

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        gInit = tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        lInit = tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                example_batch, label_batch = sess.run([examples, labels])  
                act = tf.argmax(label_batch, 1)
                fit = tf.argmax(y, 1)
                _, pAct, pFit, l, summary = sess.run([train_step, act, fit, lossFn, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: example_batch, y_: label_batch})
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
                print(pAct)
                print(pFit)

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('Finished')
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that each session.run call pulls from the queue (the first one does it explicitly, the second because the summary ops rely on queue data). Rather than using feed_dict to feed previously pulled data, if you instead have the summaries and the actual use of the queue data in the same session.run call, there will be no data thrown away. Something like:

```
examples, labels = input_pipeline(sampling_size, try_epochs)

x, y_ = examples, labels

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([TS, TL], stddev=1), name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([TL], stddev=1), name='biaes')
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b


# this one causes the issue
with tf.name_scope('Features'):
  features = examples
# this one also causes the issue
with tf.name_scope('Labels'):
  labDisp = labels
with tf.name_scope('Model'):
  myModel = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y)
with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
  lossFn = tf.reduce_mean(myModel)
with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
  train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.05).minimize(lossFn)

a1 = tf.summary.histogram("Features", features)
a2 = tf.summary.histogram("Labels", labDisp)
a3 = tf.summary.histogram("Model", myModel)
a4 = tf.summary.scalar("Loss", lossFn)

merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([a1, a2, a3, a4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  gInit = tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  lInit = tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

  summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
      act = tf.argmax(labels, 1)
      fit = tf.argmax(y, 1)
      _, pAct, pFit, l, summary = sess.run([train_step, act, fit, lossFn,
                                            merged_summary_op])
      summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
      print(pAct)
      print(pFit)

  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Finished')
  finally:
    coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but I don't understand how you'd actually serve TF the variables for the placeholders? If I run the code as you suggested, I get the error 'You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'pl_one_4' with dtype float', which makes sense, since X is the placeholder, so we need to feed it, right? But of course if I feed it, then back to square one of reading the CSV file twice?

Comment: I'd just get rid of the placeholders. The model can work directly from the queues.